# How do developers get away with writing PDF software without paying royalities to Adobe?

Tags: pdf, adobe

Example: the processtext company,

http://processtext.com/

They have dozens of PDF related utilities that do not require Adobe's products to be installed. Any while on the subject, are there available code examples for manipulating and processing PDFs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PDF is an ISO spec which Adobe released without the need to submit royalties.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

Edit: here is the legal text which licenses the patent for no charge: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/support/topic_legal_notices.html

For editing and manipulating PDFs, it depends on what your framework/language is. I use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), a port to .Net of [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), a Java library. More can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210029/pdf-libraries.

Comment: OP looks like he uses PHP from past questions, pdflib can be used there: comes in a basic free version and fully featured commercial versions

Comment: As a follow up to this, then why does amazon.com have to use the kindle under license from adobe to enable it's pdf reading ability?

Comment: @stormist: do you have a link explaining the Kindle situation?

Comment: http://blogs.adobe.com/billmccoy/2009/05/amazon_others_l.html
Looks like to uses some other technology that supports pan+zoom etc (more than just pdf reading)

Comment: @stormist: Yes, it looks like it's for an Adobe-produced library (SDK). Note that even though the spec is licensed royalty-free, that doesn't stop any one from charging for tools to read and write documents that conform to that spec.